# Need help extracting 4 numbers from HTML pull in python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, data-extraction, information-extraction

I have code written right now that opens a URL and extracts HTML data into `htmlA`

Within `htmlA` I'm trying to extract 4 pieces of information

1. A date
2. Price 1
3. Price 2
4. A percentage

The section of `htmlA` where these 4 pieces of information are embedded looks like this:

```
<!-- TAB CONTENT -->\r\n\t\t\t<div class="fund-content tab-content span12">\r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t<!-- OVERVIEW -->\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class="tab-pane active" id="overview">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<h3 class="subhead tab-header">Overview</h3>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="row-fluid">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="span6">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<p class="as-of-date">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_cph_main_cph_main_AsOfLabel">As of 9/24/2021</span>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</p>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="table-wrapper">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div>\r\n\t<table class="cefconnect-table-1 table table-striped" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" Border="0" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_cph_main_cph_main_SummaryGrid">\r\n\t\t<tr class="tr-header">\r\n\t\t\t<th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th class="right-align" scope="col">Share<br>Price</th><th class="right-align" scope="col">NAV</th><th class="right-align" scope="col">Premium/<br>Discount</th>\r\n\t\t</tr><tr>\r\n\t\t\t<td>Current</td><td class="right-align">$19.14</td><td class="right-align">$21.82</td><td class="right-align">-12.28%</
```

In this example I'm looking to extract:

1. 9/24/2021
2. $19.14
3. $21.82
4. -12.28%

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to search and extract `htmlA` but am having trouble picking off the specific bits (the 4) of information I need. Can someone help me with the code that does this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a complete answer but I can point you in the right direction.

You need to parse the html content into BeautifulSoup objects to work with the webpage content Pythonically. Like so,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elon_Musk'

html = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
```

Once you have the var soup, you can call various methods like,

```
print(soup.div)
```

Which will give you a div element, etc.

More examples:

```
soup.title
# <title>The Dormouse's story</title>

soup.title.name
# u'title'

soup.title.string
# u'The Dormouse's story'

soup.title.parent.name
# u'head'

soup.p
# <p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

soup.p['class']
# u'title'

soup.a
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>

soup.find_all('a')
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]

soup.find(id="link3")
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>
```

From https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: I tried using the method you described but the URL blocks/denies it. I think I need a method for extracting using the original way in my post above, any other ideas? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you post the code you already have? Also, what is the full error message you get? Finally, what is the URL you're trying to scrape data from?